# Need to fire an event after complete page gets loaded in backbone js

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js, page-load-time

I need to fire an event after complete page gets loaded.

I have used `Backbone js` library for my application.I have multiple ajax calls in each of  the page.But i need to fire some code after completely page gets loaded.

Comment: Take a hint from this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842090/backbone-fetch-collection-on-page-load

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [_.defer()](http://underscorejs.org/#defer).

According to the docs:

> Defers invoking the function until the current call stack has cleared, similar to using setTimeout with a delay of 0

I would use it as a last statement in `render()`.